# Jsoup select div tag return empty. Is it because the tag doesn't exists in page source?

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I'm trying to use `Jsoup` to select link form `<a>` inside `<li>` inside tag `<div class="paging">` from [here](http://search.sindonews.com/search?type=artikel&q=bni).

[image]

This is the html code(ajax) from the web page above:

```
 $.ajax({
     url: urlnext,
     beforeSend: function (xhr) {
         $('#search-load').show();
     },
     success: function (result) {
         $('#search-content').html(result);
         $('.content-left').show();
         $('#search-load').hide();
         $('.paging li a').each(function () {
             var linkPage = $(this).attr('href');
             $(this).click(function (event) {
                 event.preventDefault();
                 location.href = linkPage;
             });
         });
     }
 });
```

Here is my full code

```
1   import java.io.IOException;
2   import java.io.PrintWriter;
3   import java.util.regex.Matcher;
4   import java.util.regex.Pattern;
5
6   import org.jsoup.Connection;
7   import org.jsoup.HttpStatusException;
8   import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
9   import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
10  import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
11  import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
12
13  public class Main_sindo {
14 
15      public static void main(String[] args) IOException {
16          int searchPageNumber = 1;
17          prosesCrawling_sindo("http://search.sindonews.com/search?type=artikel&q=bni", searchPageNumber); //bni
18      }
19
20      public static void prosesCrawling_sindo(String URL){
21          try{
22              Connection.Response response = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").timeout(0).execute();
23              int statusCode = response.statusCode();
24              if(statusCode == 200){
25                  Document dok = Jsoup.connect(URL).userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").timeout(0).get();
26                  Element newsTitle = dok.select("div.article h1").first();
27                  Element newsContent = dok.select("div#content").first();
28                  if(newsContent != null){
29                      
30                      String fileName = dok.title().replaceAll("[\\/\"?:*<>|]+", " ");
31                      PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(namaFile+".txt");
32                      writer.println(isiBerita.text());
33                      writer.close();
34                  }
35              
36                  //get all links and recursively call the processPage method
37                  Elements newsPages = dok.select("div.news-content a");
38                  for(Element newsPage: newsPages){
39                      if(newsPage.attr("href").contains("sindonews.com")){
40                          prosesCrawling_sindo(newsPage.attr("abs:href"), searchPageNumber);
41                          System.out.println(newsPage.attr("abs:href"));
42                      }
43                  }
44                  
45                  //access next search page
46                  Elements nextPages = dok.select("div.paging > li > a"); //here is the problem. It seem Jsoup cannot select div class=paging (empty)
47                  for(Element nextPage: nextPages){
48                      if(nextPage != null && Integer.parseInt(nextPage.text())==searchPageNumber){
49                          if(nextPage.attr("href").contains("sindonews.com")){
50                              prosesCrawling_sindo(nextPage.attr("abs:href"), searchPageNumber);
51                          }
52                          searchPageNumber+=1;
53                      }
54                  }
55              }
56          }catch (NullPointerException e) {
57              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
58              e.printStackTrace();
59          } catch (HttpStatusException e) {
60              e.printStackTrace();
61          } catch (IOException e) {
62              // TODO Auto-generated catch block
63              e.printStackTrace();
64          }
65      }
66  }
```

The problem is is row 46 I guess.

Thank for your help before :)

Comment: Can you also attach your html document?

Answer (score 0):

You should swap your `if` conditions, first of all you should check `paging` for `null`, since the method `org.jsoup.select.Elements#first` can return `null` as a result (you can easliy check it, since jSoup is open source library).

If you try to invoke method of `null` reference, you will definitely get a NPE. So you should do your checks in reversed order:

```
if(paging == null){
    System.out.println("this is null");
}
if(paging.isEmpty()){
    System.out.println("this is empty");
}
```

And yes, it's because jSoup can not find an element matching your selector. Please, check the jSoup documentation and make sure you're using the right selector format and your document has the specified element.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation. I don't mind with if-else to check whether select method is null or empty. I just confused why the select method get nothing.

Comment: I just saw the code from the page source that the tag div class="paging" li a called by ajax